# Compound's reactivity in Hoffman Bromamide Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, amides

I already know that the presence of electron donating groups in the soon-to-be migrating group in the Hoffman Bromamide reaction makes the molecule more reactive, but I encountered a question which asks whether p-tert butyl benzamide is more reactive (w.r.t Hoffman Bromamide) or p-methyl benzamide, and the answer is the former, but shouldn't it be the latter because t-butyl group is a better EDG than just methyl?